# FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL not validating

Tags: php, validation, email

Here's the code I'm using:

```
if (filter_var($desired_username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || ((strlen($desired_username)) > 32)) {
    $usernamevalidate=FALSE;
} else {
    $usernamevalidate=TRUE;
}
```

`strlen` is working perfectly, but either filter_var or `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is not. Don't let the variable name trick you, "`$desired_username`" links to a field for an email, but it's just not working.

I can enter "test" instead of "`test@test.com`" or even "`test@test`" and it still validates. I've also tried `preg_match` and other methods, but none of them are validating properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I've also tried preg_match and other methods, but none of them are validating properly." Show us the code.

Comment: If you think `filter_var` fails - why don't you reproduce the issue without another functions? Just remove **everything** and left one line with `var_dump(filter_var(...));` and see what it returns. It is **always** a good idea to isolate the issue, and that is how debug done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

- You seem to be mixing up username and e-mail. Many e-mails are longer than 32 characters.
- You've got how `filter_var` works backwards. A valid e-mail is going to set `$usernamevalidate=FALSE` with your code.

You should be doing this instead:

```
if(filter_var($desired_username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $usernamevalidate=TRUE;
} else {
  $usernamevalidate=FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Or even `$usernamevalidate = filter_var($desired_username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice that immediately. I've been scratching my head for a couple of hours and it was something that simple. Thank you.